# Partially ordered by inclusion.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $S \neq \emptyset$ and partially order $P(S)$ by inclusion. Let $C$ be a chain and $\{s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_n\}\in \bigcup_{U \in C} U$. Prove that there is some $U \in C$ such that $\{s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_n\} \subseteq U$.

My thought is to use induction on $n$. Assume $\{s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_{n-1}\} \subseteq V \in C$ then we must have some $U \in C$ such that $x_n \in U$. Is it going to be working? And what's next? I cannot figure it out how to do it. Can someone help me please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Incidentally, in the first line of your question you mean $\{s_1, \ldots, s_n\} \subseteq \bigcup_{U\in C} U$ and not "$\in$".

**Hint 1**: Since $s_i \in \bigcup_{U\in C} U$, we have that for each $i$ there exists $U_i \in C$ such that $s_i \in U_i$.

**Claim**: $\bigcup_{i = 1}^n U_i \in C$. (Why? **Hint 2**: $C$ is a chain.)